# "path" not a valid property for Image.source

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I'm trying to change the background image set by xaml this way:

```
      <s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="WindowBackground" 
Stretch="None" Opacity="0.6" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/img/bg/Default.jpg"/>
  </s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
```

by using the following code in a method:

```
        sessionWindow.SetValue(ImageBrush.ImageSourceProperty, "..//..//Resources//img//bg//Aqua.jpg");
```

where sessionWindow is the the actual window. 
It throws the exception in the title

Comment: why use Pack uri syntax in XAML, you could just omit ""pack://application:,,," part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ImageBrush.ImageSource` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.imagesource.aspx) is of type `ImageSource`.

Therefore, you need to set it to an `ImageSource` instance.
Also, your path is wrong.

For example:

```
sessionWindow.SetValue(ImageBrush.ImageSourceProperty,
     new BitmapImage(
        new Uri(@"..\..\Resources\img\bg\Aqua.jpg", UriKind.Relative)
     )
);
```

However, this won't actually change the background - `Window` doesn't have an `ImageSource` property.
Instead, you should set the Window's `Background` property, like this:

```
sessionWindow.Background = new ImageBrush {
     ImageSource = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri(@"..\..\Resources\img\bg\Aqua.jpg", UriKind.Relative)
     )
};
```

Comment: thanks. it doesn't throw any exceptions now, but the window image is not being changed. Could it be because it's also set in the XAML ?

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  You should set the `Background` property.